# How can I parse Year integer into date in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having year col named `date` in integer format.
I tried to convert like this in BigQuery:

```
PARSE_DATE('%Y', CAST(date AS int64)) AS parsed_date
```

Error:

> No matching signature for function PARSE_DATE for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signature: PARSE_DATE(STRING, STRING) at [1:13]

Comment: it s still not clear what is your input data! please clarify!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this method, you should first call `PARSE_DATE` to get a text year, then cast to integer:

```sql
CAST(PARSE_DATE('%Y', date) AS int64) AS parsed_date
```

But maybe using `EXTRACT`, which returns an `int64`, would be easier here:

```sql
EXTRACT(year FROM date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast "date" column into string format and this should do the trick.

```
PARSE_DATE('%Y', CAST(date AS STRING)) AS parsed_date
```

Answer (score -1):

you can consider this approach.
You first need to extract the year of the date, then  convert the year to an INT64

In this code you can see a sample code:.

```
select CAST(EXTRACT (YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE()) as INT64)
```

You can see more information about [CAST](http://%5B1%5Dhttps://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#cast_as_floating_point) and [EXTRACT](http://%5B2%5Dhttps://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract_2) command in BigQuery.

Comment: `extract(year from ...)` returns `int64` so you don't need to cast it!